# Figuring out what REALLY went wrong when an `ImportError` is raised

Tags: python, exception, python-import

Take Django for instance, in `manage.py`:

```
try:
    import settings
except ImportError:
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py'...")
```

Seems legit, but what happens when `settings` imports `non_existant_lib_foo`?

Well, you're sent on a goose chase for all the possible things you could have done with `PATH`, etc.

Of course you can use `except ImportError as e:` and just print out the actual error message, but what if you want to catch only a specific error and give a really good bit of advice, like above?

You're left to using regexp more or less or, at best, guessing that the "right" module failed importing, and then display the message.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: "but what if you want to catch only a specific error and give a really good bit of advice, like above"  "The above code displays a helpful message, right? Wrong"  I can't follow this.  Generally, we just fix the import errors without doing any try/except processing at all.

Comment: Sometimes you want to note that an optional module wasn't found, but provide a user visible indication that this has happened in case it is due to a configuration error rather than being intentional.

Comment: @ncoghlan: Why is this better than the traceback?  The error is the problem.  Why wrap it?  How does that help?  The question is simply that "wrapping" the error is misleading.  So why wrap the error if the wrapped error is misleading?

Comment: @S.Lott - I'll defer to this: Do you think the Django developers just do things like that to be dumb? There is an obvious need.

Comment: Note the *optional* caveat. The only time it makes sense to suppress a failure to import a module is when it isn't a fatal error. Python itself does this in `site.py` when checking for a `sitecustomize` module: if that import fails for any reason, Python just ignores it completely. Issuing a warning when a "typically used, but not mandatory" tailoring module fails to import correctly is a reasonable middle ground.

Comment: @ncoghlan - again though, I don't need to "suppress" the error. I just need to know what the module is when it does fail so that I can issue a warning that's more specific than the method which Django enlists. Normally I'd rely on just bubbling without customized advice, but we're talking noobs using a library.

Comment: Yep, I upvoted the answer you accepted for that reason - using `imp.find_module()` to check the module exists before actually trying the import is the right tool for your use case. The Django example is actually a bit of a distraction, since it *is* suppressing the error.

Comment: This was simply broken code in Django.  It looks like it was fixed recently: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14130.  (They didn't do it to be "dumb", they did it because they--whoever wrote this code--didn't fully understand this exception.)

Comment: @Glenn - I wasn't calling them dumb. It was a rhetorical question to let S.Lott know that if Django needed a solution to this problem, then clearly it is a problem worth having a solution for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the problem is that your error message is wrong - there are other reasons why import can fail, not  just wrong paths. `ImportError` simply means "you cannot use this module, look at the traceback to find out why", you just jumped to a conclusion.

If you want to display "Can't find the file" then you should look for the file first. `imp.find_module` does that.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle cases where you don't want to let the exception propagate, but still provide some indication of the failure, is to always include the details from the original exception in whatever message you print out:

```
try:
    import settings
except ImportError as exc:
    sys.stderr.write("Error: failed to import settings module ({})".format(exc))
```

That way, you get the clear message in the common case (e.g. the user put their settings file in the wrong place, or there is a configuration error somewhere so `sys.path` is wrong), without completely obscuring any other import errors that arise in the execution of the `settings` module.

Even better, if using the logging module, is to log the full exception details (including the traceback) as a `debug()` or `info()` logging event.

There are other options, such as doing a substring search `if 'settings' not in str(exc): raise` or separating the location of the module from its execution by using `imp.find_module()`, but simply including the original error message is enough to prevent the worst hassles.

Answer (score -3):

> One thing I've found really frustrating is that when you trap an import error you're really going down a deep rabbit hole right away.

Take the hint.

Do **not** trap import errors ever.  The `manage.py` example is not a best practice.

Do not do that.

import errors should be very, very rare.

Comment: I've had to use something similar for dealing with different versions of Python, eg. `SafeConfigParser` and `ConfigParser`.

Comment: @S. Lott - I have no intention of "trapping" the errors permanently. It's nice during control flow to know where a problem comes from though so that you can do specific things, even if you do intend to re-raise.

Comment: @orokusaki: "It's nice during control flow to know where a problem comes from"  That's what the ordinary, unmodified, uncaught import exception tells you  -- it tells you **precisely** where the error comes from.  Why modify the perfect error message already provided?

Comment: @S.Lott - I don't mean me as the developer "know", I mean in the control I want my code to be able to "know" what import failed. Again, defer to Django. That helpful message could not be given, if you relied on Python's built-in exc handling.

Comment: @orokusaki: Again.  Don't defer to that single example extracted from Django.  It's not the best practice.  Code does not need to know when an import failed.  It should not fail.

Comment: @orokusaki: this is starting to sound like a feature request asking for the module name that failed import to be stored on ImportError objects, instead of being embedded as part of the already formatted argument string.

Comment: @ncoghlan - That's exactly what I was asking about (which of course I know doesn't exist, so I was more asking whether there was a replacement), but Jochen's answer removes the need.

Comment: @orokusaki: That manage.py script is the **only** example of that.  It's not a best practice.  Since that's the **only** example, here's the hint: ignore it.  It's not a best practice.  It's a completely **unique** situation that is difficult to generalize.  Don't call all of Django dumb because it has a feature that's confusing and difficult to generalize.  It's not a **best** practice.  It solves one very narrow problem that 99% of the rest of us never have.  And from your question, you don't have the problem solved by that technique.  Ignore that code.  Please.

Comment: @orokusaki: I delete wrong answers all the time.  Your approach is wrong; you don't have a "question" that needs an "answer".  You need to stop trying to replace with a good message with a less good message.  "Do you think the Django developers just do things like that to be dumb" sounds to me like you called it dumb.  "I never called django "dumb"" is a little confusing because it sure sounded like you called it dumb.  My point is this:  The exception already had specific information; if you don't catch it, you have all the information you need.